# PostgreSQL aggregate function implemented in an external C library (crashes server)

Tags: c, postgresql

I have written a C extension library for PG, using V1 calling convention. When I invoke the aggregate function, it crashes the postgres server process. I have used gdb to debug the server process and have located where the Seg-V is occuring.

It is caused by an attempt to access an invalid address. what I don't understand though is that the memory was succesfully allocated earlier on. Judging from the comment in the code though, I suspect that the memory is being harvested/released whilst still in use. I don't know enough about the internals of postgres - but this seems the likely cause of the problem.

I have included the code for the function that causes the crash and highlighted the line that causes the Seg-V. Am I calling MemoryContextAlloc with the correct parameters?

```
static PGARRAY *GetPGArray(int4 state, int fAdd);    
static PGARRAY *ShrinkPGArray(PGARRAY * p);

Datum       float8_agg_state(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);    
Datum       float8_agg_final_count(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);    
Datum       float8_agg_final_array(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);    
Datum       float8_enum(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);        

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(float8_agg_state);    
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(float8_agg_final_count);    
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(float8_agg_final_array);    
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(float8_enum);

/*    
 * Manage the aggregation state of the array    
 *    
 * Need to specify a suitably long-lived memory context, or it will vanish!    
 * PortalContext isn't really right, but it's close enough (famous last words ...).    
 */

static PGARRAY *    
GetPGArray(int4 state, int fAdd)    
{    
    PGARRAY    *p = (PGARRAY *) state;

    if (!state)    
    {    
        /* New array */    
        int cb = PGARRAY_SIZE(START_NUM);       

        p = (PGARRAY *) MemoryContextAlloc(PortalContext, cb);    
        p->a.vl_len_ = cb;    
        p->a.ndim = 0;    
        p->a.dataoffset = 0;

#ifndef PG_7_2    
        p->a.elemtype = FLOAT8OID;    
#endif

        p->items = 0;    
        p->lower = START_NUM; 
    }
    else if (fAdd)    
    {       
           /* Ensure array has space */

           /* SEG-V fault on the line below */
        if (p->items >= p->lower)    
        {    
            PGARRAY *pn;    
            int n = p->lower + p->lower;   
            int cbNew = PGARRAY_SIZE(n);

            pn = (PGARRAY *) repalloc(p, cbNew);    
            pn->a.vl_len_ = cbNew;    
            pn->lower = n;    
            return pn;   
        }    
    }

    return p;    
}
```

Can anyone spot why the code SG-V's?

**[[Edit]]**

My backend PG server is v8.4.9

Answer (score 1):

there should be more issues - wrong registration, wrong format of returned data, wrong memory context of returned data - good patter you can find in array_agg implementation http://doxygen.postgresql.org/array__userfuncs_8c_source.html

```
00477 array_agg_transfn(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
00478 {
00479     Oid         arg1_typeid = get_fn_expr_argtype(fcinfo->flinfo, 1);
00480     MemoryContext aggcontext;
00481     ArrayBuildState *state;
00482     Datum       elem;
00483 
00484     if (arg1_typeid == InvalidOid)
00485         ereport(ERROR,
00486                 (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE),
00487                  errmsg("could not determine input data type")));
00488 
00489     if (!AggCheckCallContext(fcinfo, &aggcontext))
00490     {
00491         /* cannot be called directly because of internal-type argument */
00492         elog(ERROR, "array_agg_transfn called in non-aggregate context");
00493     }
00494 
00495     state = PG_ARGISNULL(0) ? NULL : (ArrayBuildState *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
00496     elem = PG_ARGISNULL(1) ? (Datum) 0 : PG_GETARG_DATUM(1);
00497     state = accumArrayResult(state,
00498                              elem,
00499                              PG_ARGISNULL(1),
00500                              arg1_typeid,
00501                              aggcontext);
00502 
00503     /*
00504      * The transition type for array_agg() is declared to be "internal", which
00505      * is a pass-by-value type the same size as a pointer.  So we can safely
00506      * pass the ArrayBuildState pointer through nodeAgg.c's machinations.
00507      */
00508     PG_RETURN_POINTER(state);
00509 }
```

This is for 9.1 - if you have older version, look to related source code.

Comment: I forgot to mention my backend db was 8.4. The code used to work for earlier versions of PG though. Could you post a link the relevant doc for 8.4?. The doc you provided a link to makes no reference to 9.1 - can it be used for 8.4 code?

Comment: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-committers/2008-11/msg00159.php http://anoncvs.postgresql.org/cvsweb.cgi/pgsql/src/backend/utils/adt/array_userfuncs.c?r1=1.23&r2=1.24 this is 8.4 patch